# versionone -- How do i find a program(s) a story may be associated with from the rest-1.v1/Data/Story api

Tags: versionone

I have a report that looks for all stories in progress that do not have data in an assest we added.
I need to filter the report future to limit those being reported on such that I know the stories are associated with any of nine “Programs”.

Is there a way from `rest-1.v1/Data/Story` schema to see what program(s) the story may be part of?

I have searched the community and V1 docs and looked through the schema but have not found the proper way to do this.

Through the VersionOne web pages I see under “Reports” –  “Program Quicklist” for “All Projects” and the filter set properly the nine programs I want to allow for.
If I hover over the Programs, shown under the “Title” column, I see a url like  `.../Program.mvc/Summary?oidToken=ScopeLabel%3A153263`
This uses `Program.mvc` and the token of `ScopeLabel` with the Program ID number.

Anyway, I’m still trying to find the asset name to use as I do my query like:
 `.../rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Name,Scope.ID,Scope.Name,Status,AssetState,Custom_AcceptanceCriteria&where=Status.Name='In+Progress';Scope.ParentMeAndUp='Scope:16484';AssetState='64'`

to be able to determine if the result shows the story is part of one of the nine Programs that we want to specifically report.

Again, any thoughts on how I can get the data on which, if any, "Program"  the story may belong to?

Answer (score 2):

You are close. I am going to spell it out for the community.

Based on this [map of VersionOne AssetTypes to various methodologies,](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Concepts/Asset_Type) and your detective work with the hover URL, it seems like you mean what VersionOne calls a `ScopeLabel`.  Looking at the [VersionOne server Meta endpoint](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/meta.v1), I see that `ScopeLabel` doesn't seem to have any attribute like `Workitems` or `Stories`, but it does have `Scopes` and I know that `Scopes` have `Workitems`, which include Stories.  I also know I can follow the chain backwards through the reciprocal relations.

*For this example, I am going to use an expanded format and not url-encode this.*  (As you know, in normal usage it would need to have the whitespace removed and the values url-encoed).

So I might start out with a query such as:

```
~/rest-1.v1/Data/Story
  ?where=Scope.ScopeLabels.Name='Program 1','Program 2','Program 3'
```

The filter token syntax allows `,` to introduce multiple values, though it's not documented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually saw this a few hours ago, but being new to StackOverflow I could not post my answer back for 8 hours. Digging more into the schema for Scope provided me the correct answer. I had tried to select on Scope.ScopeLabel at one point, which did not work. When I re-read the Scope doc it appears I needed to use the plural Scope.ScopeLabels.

So, the query would be like: ".../rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Name,Scope.ID,Scope.Name,Status,AssetState,Custom_AcceptanceCriteria,Scope.ScopeLabels&where=Status.Name='In+Progress';Scope.ParentMeAndUp='Scope:16484';AssetState='64'"

Comment: - I tried also adding values for the "with" part of the query. I don't know that I have done this correctly as I get different results when I do additional where clauses on each of 9 items in my with. When I uses the where I limit the results from 266 items returned down to a aggregate of 39. Using the with clause I get all 266 that I would obtain without using the with. I'll put my query in the next comment. It is urlencoded.

Comment: My query is <Base URL)/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Name,Scope.ID,Scope.Name,Status,AssetState,Custom_AcceptanceCriteria,Scope.ScopeLabels.Name&where=Status.Name='In+Progress';Scope.ParentMeAndUp='Scope:16484';AssetState='64'&with=Scope.ScopeLabels.Name='P-2013-Q4-DPT%2CP-2013-Q4-Engineering+Services+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-FamilySearch+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-Partner+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-RecordsCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-SearchProductCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-Standards+and+Authorities+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-TempleCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-TreeCouncil'

Comment: Well, I didn't understand the `with` syntax either and led you down the wrong path.  Please see the corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks. Isee that this works. I also got your previous version to work to with the where=Scope.ScopeLabels.Name=$program&w‌ith=$program='Program 1', 'Program 2', 'Program 3'.  It's good to see it works both ways. (I did have to add the $ on program as I was working in PHP.)